# How to import excel without additional columns on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a function that is able to output the changes between two datasets. One dataset was handed to me in csv format, and another was handed to be in excel rich text format. However, when I tried to import the excel sheet to jupyter notebook using pd.read_excel(), there were additional columns that came about (I think) because the excel sheet had some values that were hyperlinked and/or linked to other excel sheets in a larger workbook.

For example:

**Original excel sheet**

| Header1 | Header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Hyperlink1 | xxx(linked to other sheets) |
| HYperlink2 | yyy (linked to other sheets) |

When imported into jupyter notebook:

| Header1 | Header 2 | URL - Header1 | Header2 Look Up |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hyperlink1 | xxx (linked to other sheets) | [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) | xxx |
| HYperlink2 | yyy (linked to other sheets) | [www.bcd.com](http://www.bcd.com) | yyy |

I am wondering if there was a way to import an excel sheet to output a table that is similar to importing a csv file.

And if not, is there a way to know which columns have been added on top of what was present in the original excel sheet?

Comment: If you know which columns you want can't you remove them from the imported data? Or you could use the `usecols` argument of  `read_excel` to specify which columns to import.

Comment: Hi @norie, yeaps! But eventually, I want a function that is able to take in both csv and excel formats, and output the changes between the 2 of them. So the column names are not always the same.

Comment: How will you be able to compare the datasets if you don't know the column names? Also, how will you know which columns from the Excel file to import?

Comment: Basically, I want to create a function that is able to take in 2 datasets and output the differences (which columns have been changed, which columns have been added and deleted, etc). However, I want to take into account the fact that some of these changes are due to the importing process,  (especially with excel sheets)